# Algorithms that can only be written in assembly

Tags: algorithm

*Any algorithm you can implement in a HLL you can implement in assembly. On the other hand, there are many algorithms you can implement in assembly which you cannot implement in a HLL.* - Randall Hyde

I found this statement in the forward to a book on assembly. The book is here: https://courses.engr.illinois.edu/ece390/books/artofasm/fwd/fwd.html#109

Does anyone know an example of this type of algorithm?

Comment: It depends on what one means by _algorithm_. In the pure sense, an _algorithm_ is a machine-independent description of how to go about solving a particular computing problem. Since there is no such thing as a machine-independent assembly language--by which I mean an assembly language for a machine that has no specification--an algorithm _can't_ be described in a way that can only be implemented in assembly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a sense in which it is trivially false: in the worst case, you could write an emulator in the HLL and then run the algorithm in there. But that's cheating a bit because now the HLL does not directly implement the algorithm.

A concrete example of what many HLL's can't do (or maybe they can in practice, but it is not guaranteed that they can do it), is directly implementing a XOR linked list. In many languages you just cannot XOR pointers, and/or it wouldn't make sense even if you could (consider garbage collection). Of course you can refer to every node by an integer ID and XOR those, but that's a workaround, not a direct implementation.

HLL's often have trouble implementing unstructured control flow, though many (particularly older) languages offer a `goto`. That means you may have to jump through hoops to implement a state machine (using a switch in a loop or whatever), instead of letting the state be implied by the program counter.

There are also many algorithms and data structures that rely on operations that don't exist in typical HLL's, for example `popcnt` or `lzcnt`, which can again be emulated, but then so can everything.

Answer (score 3):

It's plain wrong.

You can implement any algorithm (in the CS sense of the word) in any turing complete programming language.

On the other hand, if he would have said something a like: "Some algorithms can be implemented very efficiently, and with ease in assembly, much more so than what is possible in most high level programming languages", then his statement would have made sense...

Interesting text though....

Answer (score 1):

In case you have strict limitations in terms of memory and/or execution time, you might be forced to use assembly language.

High level languages typically require a run-time library which might be too big to fit into your program memory.

Think of a time-critical driver routine. An interrupt service routine for example. If there are only a few nanoseconds available for the routine, assembly language might be the only viable option.

Comment: ^ This. Any algorithm can be written within any turing complete language as says the answer by @AK_, but if memory is limited, or even the instruction set, you need to do it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

How about [this](https://github.com/jbangert/trapcc)? You need to write some assembly code in order to access system registers and tables. But onces the setup is done, no CPU instructions are executed (everything's done by the complex CPU exception handling mechanisms) and yet the thing is Turing-complete and can "run" programs.